# How to set global configuration for angular-cli?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli

I would like to make my `ng serve` command default with `liveReload` = `false`.

I tried `ng config --global serve.options.liveReload false` but I got an `Invalid Path` error.

Also I want to know specifically how to edit the global config, no changing of local project files.

Answer (score 0):

2022. If you are looking for the global CLI config, I found it here on Windows:

%USERPROFILE%\angular-config.json

Answer (score -1):

Go to your `angular.json` file, look for you `serve` section and change `options`.

```
...
"projects": {
  "myorg": {
    ...
    "architect": {
      ...
      "serve": {
        "options": {
          ...
          "liveReload": false,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will make your `ng serve` run `ng serve --liveReload=false`.
Check the docs [here](https://angular.io/cli/serve) to find all options.

Comment: Where is the global angular.json located on Windows?

Comment: It is not related to the operating system. It is related to the project, it is placed at the root level of your project, along with your `package.json` and stuff.

Comment: But I specifically said that I am working with the GLOBAL configuration. I am not interested in configuring it per project. My question is related to `npm config --global` which implies the GLOBAL configuration, unrelated to any project.

Comment: well, you can't